# How to resolve a merge conflict in Git?

Tags: git, merge, version-control, conflict

I am working on a project with a team and we are using Git for version control. I recently pulled the latest changes from the remote repository and tried to merge them with my local branch. However, I encountered a merge conflict. I am not sure how to resolve this conflict. Can anyone guide me through the process?

I tried to manually edit the conflicting files by choosing the changes I want to keep. However, I am not sure if this is the correct way to resolve a merge conflict. I also tried to use the `git merge --abort` command to abort the merge, but I still need to merge the changes.

Comment: Edit the files and set them the way you need, then you add them to index (`git add blahblah`), then `git merge --continue` so that git can wrap it and create the resulting commit.

Comment: Make sure that the tool you are using to resolve the conflicts with is a proper 3-way merge tool (e.g. with 4 window panes!). I highly recommend [using KDiff3](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3).